# How to freeze molecular orbitals in GAMESS-US?

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, gamess

I want to freeze some of the orbitals (e.g 1s orbital for all of the atoms in my molecule) in GAMESS-US, to save computation time. I guess I need to use $MOFRZ but I'm not sure how to. So far, I've created the input file as follows:

```
 $CONTRL SCFTYP=RHF CCTYP=CCSD(T) RUNTYP=ENERGY ICHARG=1
       UNITS=ANGS ISPHER=1 $END
!   
 $SCF DIIS=.TRUE. $END
 $GUESS GUESS=MOREAD NORB=69 $END
 $MOFRZ FRZ=.TRUE. IFRZ(1)=1,10,19,28 $END
!
 $SYSTEM MWORDS=1500 $END
!
  $VEC   
 1  1-9.95521651E-06-3.24237240E-06-5.54660060E-06-2.93436786E-04 1.30027027E-02
.
.
.
69 55-9.89984798E-03-1.24161440E-03-4.86737205E-04 2.96787026E-03-1.28394192E-03
69 56 1.26297389E-02-3.44011121E-02-9.31840053E-04-1.12673533E-03-2.64710788E-03
 $END
 $DATA
C1
.
.
.
 $END
 $BASIS
    GBASIS=KTZVP
 $END
```

When I run this input, I get the following error:

```
                   * * * * * WARNING * * * * *
 POSSIBLE LINEAR DEPENDENCE PROBLEMS DETECTED, INPUT QMTTOL= 1.0E-06,
 WITH     2 OVERLAP EIGENVALUES LYING BETWEEN 1.0E-05 AND QMTTOL.
 IF YOU EXPERIENCE SCF CONVERGENCE DIFFICULTIES WITH THE DENSITY ALMOST BUT
 NOT QUITE CONVERGED, YOU MAY NEED TO LOOSEN -QMTTOL- BY A FACTOR 5 TO 10.
 NO $VEC INPUT FOUND - STOP
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the error `NO $VEC INPUT FOUND` means that GAMESS did not find molecular orbitals to read in. This is because you wrote two spaces before `$VEC` in the input file, i.e.   `$VEC`. But it is supposed to be only 1 space, i.e.  `$VEC`.

Secondly, I suggest that put the `$VEC` section into the final paragraph/section in the input file. This makes the input more readable since we should first know the coordinates and the basis set, and then we(or the program) determine the size of arrays to hold overlap integrals, molecular coefficients, etc. I'm not sure that whether the `$VEC` section can be put before coordinates and basis set.

Thirdly, frozen core is default for CCSD(T) in GAMESS. The default is the number of chemical core orbitals. For example, 1s for the oxygen atom. You can check the number of frozen orbitals in output via searching `NUMBER OF FROZEN CORE MOS`. If you do not want the default one, you can specify `NCORE=n` in `$CCINP`, where n is the number of frozen orbitals you want. Besides, you can freeze some highest virtual orbitals if you are an experienced user (`NFZV=m` in `$CCINP`, default is 0). As far as I know, `$MOFRZ` is used in RHF, ROHF and GVB (i.e. SCF-type jobs), but not in post-HF calculations.

If you want more customized frozen cores, I guess you should first run a HF calculation, visualize the occupied orbitals, alter/permute orbitals to make sure the orbitals to be frozen lies in the lowest occupied ones. In this case, you may still use `NCORE=n` since orbitals have been permuted as you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! This is a great explanation. I have a question to your answer if I would want to 2s2 orbital of CARBON11 atom in my input (so, a specific atom, not all carbons), should I do `$MOFRZ` in RHF and then move to Post-HF calculations? Because the 1s2 is already frozen from the default `NCORE` value.

Comment: Usually people do not freeze any orbital during the SCF procedure. I suggest not to use the `$MOFRZ`. It takes at least three steps to get what you want: (1) perform RHF and localize occupied orbitals (add `LOCAL=POP` in `$CONTRL`, specify `$LOCAL FCORE=.F. $END`); (2) visualize localized occupied orbitals and permute them(you'll need `NORDER` and `IORDER` in `$GUESS`); (3) read orbitals in, set `NCORE` properly, and perform CCSD(T). This may be a little troublesome so I suggest you try some small molecules (e.g. H2O) first.